# HTTP.get request stuck in a redirect loop

Tags: node.js, meteor, http-get

I have the below lines in my code:

```
postUrl =  "http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/08/world/asia/ malaysia-airlines-says-plane-with-over-200-aboard-is-missing.html";

var htmlResult = cheerio.load(Meteor.http.call("GET", postUrl, {options: {followRedirects:false}}).content);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop
```

I try the same code with other URL and it works but It's throwing this exception with the NTY url. I'm basically trying to get the HEAD of the page.

Answer (score 9):

Use [this](https://atmospherejs.com/dandv/http-more).

In your `http.get` call you should pass `{jar: true}`

For example:

```
HTTP.get(url, {jar: true})
```

This worked for me at least :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your url. Is that causing an issue?